# How to enter input separated by semi colon by using setInputMask()

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qdir, qstringlist

My goal is to display only files which user wants to see. For instance, "*.h; *.txt" as an input should shows the only *.h and *.txt files in selected folder. The program works for only one input(ie. *.h) The code:

```
QString mask = ";";
 QStringList stringList(ui->lineEdit->text());
ui->lineEdit->setInputMask(mask);

QFileInfoList fileList = qdir.entryInfoList(QStringList() << stringList, QDir::Files, QDir::Size);
```

The program display when the users enter input only one type of file:
[image]

But it does not display when the users enter input as *.h; *.cpp
[image]

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
All I need to do was

```
QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
QStringList stringList = str.split(QLatin1Char(';'));
QFileInfoList fileList = qdir.entryInfoList(QStringList() << stringList, QDir::Files, QDir::Size);
```